# Does SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core edition support Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2012

As I knew SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core edition does not support the GUI, however, there are some questions below to confirm.

Does SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core edition work in a Windows Server 2008 environment (not Windows Server Core 2008 environment)?

If yes, can I manage SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core edition via SQL Server 2012 Management Studio?

I have no idea about the difference between SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core edition and SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

The name Enterprise Core refers to the licensing, not the restrictions of the OS.  Enterprise and Enterprise Core are functionally the same product, and will install on the same OS enviornments, so yes you can use SSMS.

Best explanation I could find is here: https://serverfault.com/a/604682